# Python: Using itertools to get previous, current, and next item in list from text file

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have setup my code as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012089/571600) (shown below):

```
from itertools import tee, islice, chain, izip

def previous_and_next(some_iterable):
    prevs, items, nexts = tee(some_iterable, 3)
    prevs = chain([None], prevs)
    nexts = chain(islice(nexts, 1, None), [None])
    return izip(prevs, items, nexts)

x = open('out2.txt','r')
lines = x.readlines()

for previous, item, next in previous_and_next(lines):
    print "Current: ", item , "Next: ", next, "Previous: ", previous
    if item == '0':
        print "root"
    elif item == '2':
        print "doc"
    else:
        print "none"

x.close()
```

`out2.txt` looks like this:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
```

This code works fine when using something like `list = [0,2,4,6,8,10]` but not when using the lines of a text file into a list. How can I use the lines of a text file as a list. Isn't `x.readlines()` doing this? Ultimately I need to be able to print output depending on the `item, next, and previous` results.

Current output is:

```
Current:  0
Next:  2
Previous:  None
none
Current:  2
Next:  4
Previous:  0

none
Current:  4
Next:  6
Previous:  2

none
Current:  6
Next:  8
Previous:  4

none
Current:  8
Next:  10 Previous:  6

none
Current:  10 Next:  None Previous:  8

none
```

Desired output should be:

```
Current:  0
Next:  2
Previous:  None
**root**

Current:  2
Next:  4
Previous:  0
**doc**

none
Current:  4
Next:  6
Previous:  2

none
Current:  6
Next:  8
Previous:  4

none
Current:  8
Next:  10 Previous:  6

none
Current:  10 Next:  None Previous:  8

none
```

Comment: In which way does the code fail?  "It does not work fine" is rather useless information.

Comment: Added what the output currently looks like and what I'm trying to make it look like.

Comment: Note that, instead of a sequence of `if`s, you can use a dictionary to map strings (node types?) to other strings (node names?). This is even simpler if you use a [default-dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/389639-default-dictionary/), which isn't a native type in Python, but is easily implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readlines()` method of a file object returns a list of the lines of the file *including the newline characters*.  Your checks compare with strings not including newline characters, so they always fail.

One way of getting rid of the newline characters is

```
lines = (line.strip() for line in open("out2.txt"))
```

(Note that you don't need `readlines()` -- you can directly iterate over the file object itself.)