# looping into different positions of a list

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I would like to loop into a list of pandas dataframe variables, but with the possibility of choosing different index positions

```
raw_data = {'v1': [10,np.nan,50,30],'v2': [10,-10,50,-20],'v3':[120,-130,509,-230],'v4': [5,78,34,66]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['v1','v2','v3','v4'])

columns = ['v1','v2','v3','v4']

#pseudo code: i+1 represents the following element in the list, after "i" element
for i in columns:
    print(df[i])
    print(df[i+1])
```

in real life I would like to do more complex operations to pairs of variables, like applying a function to v1 and v3, then v2 and v4, then v3 and v5, etc.

for instance: create a new var called 'new_varv1, which is the difference between v1 and v3. then the loop will do the same with v2 and v4, storing the result in new_varv2, etc

```
for i in columns:
    df['new_var'+i]=df[i]-df[i+2]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you post your desired output?

Comment: I edited the text with more explications, @qbzenker

Comment: what would you prefer for the first pair 'v1','v2'?

Comment: yes could be, but I'm looking for a flexable approach, so it could be also v1-v3

Comment: as I said in my answer already covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011938/python-previous-and-next-values-inside-a-loop If you unhappy usage of index variable in standard solution might be better to create a different question (looping funky? elegantly?).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
ctr = 1
for i in columns:
    print(df[i])
    print(df[columns[ctr]])
    ctr+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic and recommended way is enumerate()

https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html

```
for (i, c) in enumerate(columns, start=1):
        print(df[c])
        print(df[columns[i-1]])
```

See [Python - Previous and next values inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011938/python-previous-and-next-values-inside-a-loop)

for more convoluted examples

Sometimes, if only previous/next element needed I use

```
prev = df[columns[0]]
if columns
    for i in columns[1:]:
        next = df[i] 
        print(next)
        print(prev)
        prev = next
```

Or just resort to classic loop

```
for i in range(len(columns)-1):
    print(df[columns[i]])
    print(df[columns[i+1]])
```

If you feel funky

```
for next, prev in zip(columns, columns[0:]):
    print(df[next])
    print(df[prev])
```

The index, provided in the enumerate solution is helpful to check 
that index value does not go beyond list boundaries.

If you strongly dislike using index variable, you might be able
to use deque, which is list like  and, probably try-except to silence boundary errors

```
from collections import deque
c = deque(columns)
for c0 in c[1:-3]:

    print(df[c0])
    print(df[c[-1]])

    print(df[c[3]])
    c.rotate(-1)
```

Comment: the xrange does not print anything. I would need something like this: for (i, c) in enumerate(columns): 
    print(df[c]),print(df[c[-1]])

Comment: you should use index in code and yet make sure index does not go beyond the array boundaries: by checking array boundaries, or (in your simple case) by adjusting the loop range.

Comment: An interesting question, can one make you code correct by tinkering with c type. Not sure is it possible, may be one have resort to OOP? One idea is tinker with dequeue `from collections import deque;
past_n_future = deque(columns[:]);
for c in columns:
     print(c); print past_n_future[-1]; print past_n_future[3]; past_n_future.rotate(-1)`