# Getting the next item in a python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML object that contains a list if an 'X' is found I want to print the x and the next item in the list:

```
for string in tr[30].strings:
      if string == 'X':
              print(string)
              print(string.next())
```

Getting error:

TypeError: 'NavigableString' object is not callable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Previous and next values inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011938/python-previous-and-next-values-inside-a-loop)

Comment: Much, *much* easier: track the previous item. Store each `string` into `previous` at the end of the loop, then just check `if previous == 'X':`, at which point `string` is the 'next' value after `'X'`.

Comment: What happens if you do `string.next` instead of `string.next()`?

Comment: It's worth noting none of the answers so far address `NavigableString` objects... so they may have a better option than the general approaches given.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I used your method and it worked flawlessly.

>>> for string in tr[30].strings:
...     if string != '\n':
...             if previous == 'X':
...                     print(string)
...             previous = string

Answer (score 6):

You can use `enumerate`, example:

```
strings = tr[30].strings 

for index, string in enumerate(strings):
    if string == 'X':
        print(string)
        print(strings[index + 1])
```

Comment: Tried it got an error.
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
theIterator = iter(tr[30].strings)

for string in theIterator:
      if string == 'X':
              print(string)
              print(next(theIterator))
```

But be aware that manipulating the iterator of a running for-loop is not recommend.

Comment: `next` isn't called like this. You'd skip a `string` if `string` is `X`, which isn't the case in OP question.

Comment: you should use `next(theIterator)`, `.next` only works in Python 2.

Comment: @EricDuminil It's not clear what the OP exactly wants regarding this behavior (ok, I could have asked)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you