# Sort List According to time intervall

Tags: python, list

I have two list:

```
time_sentence = 
[[11000, 'sen1'], [18000, 'sen2'], [24000, 'sen3'], [40000, 'sen4'], [54000, "sen5"], [61000, "sen6"]]


time_intervalls = [11000, 25000,50000,70000]
```

The first list is a 2D array of (time, string) and the second list is a list of specific time stamps. Now, I would like to know, how I can extract all the sentences that belong according to their time in-between two time-stamps ?

Expected result:

```
sentences= [['sen1','sen2','sen3'],['sen4'],['sen5','sen6']]
```

Comment: You can do that with a simple loop. Have you tried?

Comment: Where would `sen3` go if it were at 25000? are bounds inclusive? Read [ask].

Comment: It may not be that easy, but you are supposed to do some research and show a honest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
time_sentence = [[11000, 'sen1'], [18000, 'sen2'], [24000, 'sen3'], [40000, 'sen4'], [54000, "sen5"], [61000, "sen6"]]
time_intervals = [11000, 25000, 50000, 70000]

l = len(time_intervals)
sentences = []

for index,obj in enumerate(time_intervals):

    current = obj
    sentence = []

    if index < (l - 1):
        next_ = time_intervals[index + 1]

        for row in range(len(time_sentence)):
            if current <= time_sentence[row][0] <= next_:
                sentence.append(time_sentence[row][1])

        if sentence != []:
            sentences.append(sentence)

print(sentences)
```

Reference: [Python - Previous and next values inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011938/10155936)