# How to access next element in a list using a for loop

Tags: python

If I have a loop for example:

```
for i in nums: 
    print(i) #print current item
    print(NEXT ITEM IN LIST FROM CURRENT POS)
```

How would I get it to print the current item and then the next item relevant to the current item?

I want it to print every first item + the next item
so a list of nums 1 2 3 4 5 would print:

`1
2
3
4
5`

not

`1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5`

I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(nums):
    print(i) # print current item
    if idx < len(nums) - 1: # check if index is out of bounds
        print(nums[idx+1])
```

---

Concerning your follow up question on how to handle two elements per list iteration, without repeating any elements, you can use `range` with a step of `2`, e.g.

```
for idx in range(0, len(nums), 2):
    print(nums[idx])
    if idx < len(nums) - 1:
        print(nums[idx+1])
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I edited my question to specify something extra, would you know how to correct that?

Comment: In your example you only print every element once. I don't see how this does not contradict your original question.

Comment: When I run the code on a list of nums 1 2 3 4 5 it prints as follows:
`
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
`

Comment: That is what you should expect from the question you asked.

Comment: Yeah that is true, but how would I go about getting it to print the current element and the next element, then in the next iteration of the loop not print the current one but the one after that? so that it prints 1 2 3 4 5 but 2 at a time in each iteration? I hope it makes sense

Comment: Why are you overcomplicating this? If you want to print line after line, you just iterate through the list and print the current element.

Comment: The question in hand is just a simplified version of a bigger problem, but I asked it that way to make it easier to understand. Thanks for the help mate, sorry to be a pain

Comment: I edited my answer for this case.

Answer (score 4):

You can `zip` through your list:

```
for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:]):
    print(x, y, sep='\n')
```

Comment: It's probably most "pythonic" way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `print(num[I])` for the current item and `print(num[I+1])` for the next. but make sure to not access the next element when I is the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enumerate` function

Find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011938/python-previous-and-next-values-inside-a-loop). There is already similar post for the mentioned issue.