# Get to the previous element in list using for loop

Tags: python

Imagine I have a list of values and I want to compare current value with previous value of the list using for loop. How to do that?

Comment: you just use the previous index...? if the current index is `i`, the previous element is at `i-1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python loop that also accesses previous and next values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011938/python-loop-that-also-accesses-previous-and-next-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing your for loop like this (which is the preferred way)

```
for element in list:
    do_something()
```

You can do this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    element = list[i]
    previous_element = list[i-1]
    do_something()
```

Pay attention that in the first iteration, `i` will be 0 so `list[i-1]` will give the last element of the list, not the previous, since there is no previous.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using `for...in variable` and hence do not have the indexes, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is the pythonic way to achieve what you want.

```py
for index, current_item in enumerate(variable):
    prev = variable[index - 1] if index > 0 else None
    # Use prev and current_item here
```